# Testing vue3 quasar QRange event is emitted in jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I have the following template:

```
<template>
  <q-range
    class="number-range-slider"
    v-model="rangeValues"
    :label="false"
    :min="rangeMin"
    :max="rangeMax"
    :step="step"
    snap
    @update:model-value="(val) => onDrag(val)"
    @change="(val) => onSelectionChange(val)"
    color="blue"
  />
</template>
```

With the following method:

```
  methods: {
    onDrag(range: Range<number>): void {
      this.labels = range;
      this.$emit('onDrag', range);
    },
    onSelectionChange(range: Range<number>): void {
      console.log(range);
      this.$emit('onSelectionChange', range);
    },
  },
```

The following test fails to find the `onSelectionChange` event, the error is the received value is `undefined`, what can I do to fix this issue?

```
describe('NumberRangeSlider', (): void => {
  it('emits the event `onSelectionChange` when the range has been changed', async () => {
    const slider = wrapper.findComponent(QRange);
    await slider.trigger('change');
    expect(slider.emitted('onSelectionChange')).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```